# how to say it if you used a wrong window on you instant messanger?

Tags: phrases

Can I use - oops wrong window? Sorry, I meant someone else? or...?

I'm talking about very informal situation when you are (text) chatting through Skype or other IM with several friends at the same time and every single conversation is displayed in a separate window. By mistake, you write and send something what was intended to someone else. :)
Thank you.

Comment: "Oops, wrong window!  Ignore what I just sent." is fine.  Do it quickly, vs spending time trying to come up with a clever turn of phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sorry, wrong window.

Would be fine. It's terse, but not so terse as to be rude, and its a context in which people are already expecting messages to be short.

It's not a full grammatical sentence like "I'm sorry, I accidentally typed in the wrong window", but that doesn't matter; people will understand the meaning and this sort of elision is common in several contexts.

(This is assuming that you typed something relatively innocent. If you've accidentally written something uncomplimentary about someone to the person you were writing about, or accidentally sent an erotic message to your colleague instead of your lover, then it might be necessary to be a bit more verbose than that).

Comment: +1 I wonder how successful that excuse would be to a peeping-tom caught looking through a garage window thinking that it was the bathroom!

Answer (score 1):

You could use window, however, I think in this context, you could use the term "conversation" or "chat" or even the initials "IM" and I think you would be successful in getting across your desired meaning.